# Git svn broken again on OS X

Tags: macos, git, git-svn, osx-mavericks

I just recently upgraded to OS X Mavericks and I wish I would have waited a little longer. Now when I try to run "git svn" I get the following error.

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _Perl_Gthr_key_ptr
>     Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/../Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.bundle
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _Perl_Gthr_key_ptr
>     Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/../Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.bundle
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>
> error: git-svn died of signal 5

I tried what was suggested [here](http://undefinedvalue.com/2013/08/21/solving-symbol-not-found-perlgthrkeyptr-when-running-git-svn-certain-unnamed-operating-sy) to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up having to upgrade my xcode verison. I was on 3.x but once I upgraded to 5.1 git svn works.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this part of my [helper script](https://github.com/liyanage/macosx-shell-scripts/blob/master/update-git.sh#L32) that I use to update git works for you:

```
# To prevent missing SVN/Core.pm
# http://victorquinn.com/blog/2012/02/19/fix-git-svn-in-mountain-lion/

PERL_LIB_DIR=/Library/Perl/5.16
PERL_LIB_DIR_PLATFORM=$PERL_LIB_DIR/darwin-thread-multi-2level
XCODE_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app

sudo mkdir -p $PERL_LIB_DIR_PLATFORM/auto/
[ -e $PERL_LIB_DIR_PLATFORM/auto/SVN  ] && sudo rm $PERL_LIB_DIR_PLATFORM/auto/SVN
sudo ln -s $XCODE_PATH/Contents/Developer$PERL_LIB_DIR_PLATFORM/auto/SVN $PERL_LIB_DIR_PLATFORM/auto/

sudo mkdir -p $PERL_LIB_DIR/
[ -e $PERL_LIB_DIR/SVN ] && sudo rm $PERL_LIB_DIR/SVN
sudo ln -s $XCODE_PATH/Contents/Developer$PERL_LIB_DIR_PLATFORM/SVN $PERL_LIB_DIR/
```

You might want to use [`xcode-select`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html) instead of the hardcoded path I use here.

Answer (score 0):

I used the guide from this [link](http://undefinedvalue.com/2013/08/21/solving-symbol-not-found-perlgthrkeyptr-when-running-git-svn-certain-unnamed-operating-sy), and could bypass this error by using xcrun.

e.g.

xcrun git svn rebase

Had to run it as root, to go through the license agreement (only for the first time).